# How can I initialize in onResponse function? (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit, runtimeexception

I thought when `response.body()?.let {}` run, `enrollBookAdapter` (or `booklist = it.books as mutableList<book>`) would be initialized but, it did not... What am I doing wrong? How can I initailize bookList with Books...

```
class EnrollBookActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityEnrollBookBinding
    private lateinit var bookService: BookService
    private lateinit var bookList:MutableList<Book>
    private lateinit var enrollBookAdapter: EnrollBookAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityEnrollBookBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)


        initBookService()
        bookServiceLoadBestSellers()


        binding.selfBtn.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this,SelfWriteActivity::class.java))
        }
        enrollBookAdapter.setOnBookClickListener(object:EnrollBookAdapter.OnBookClickListener{
            override fun onBookClick(position: Int, book: Book) {
                val intent = Intent(this@EnrollBookActivity,TalerMain::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("title",enrollBookAdapter.bookList[position].title)
                intent.putExtra("url",enrollBookAdapter.bookList[position].title)
                
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        })
    }
    private fun initBookRecyclerView(bookList: MutableList<Book>) {
        enrollBookAdapter = EnrollBookAdapter(bookList)
        enrollBookAdapter.setOnBookClickListener(object:EnrollBookAdapter.OnBookClickListener{
            override fun onBookClick(position: Int, book: Book) {
                val intent = Intent(this@EnrollBookActivity,TalerMain::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("title",enrollBookAdapter.bookList[position].title)
                intent.putExtra("url",enrollBookAdapter.bookList[position].title)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        })
        binding.bookRv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        binding.bookRv.adapter = EnrollBookAdapter(bookList)
        binding.bookRv.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
    }
    private fun bookServiceLoadBestSellers() {
        bookService.getBestSellerBooks(getString(R.string.interparkAPIKey))
            .enqueue(object : Callback<BestSellerDto> {
                
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<BestSellerDto>,
                    response: Response<BestSellerDto>
                ) {
                    
                    if (response.isSuccessful.not()) {
                        Log.e(M_TAG, "NOT!! SUCCESS")
                        return
                    }

                    
                    response.body()?.let {
                        Log.d(M_TAG, it.toString())

                        it.books.forEach { book ->
                            Log.d(M_TAG, book.toString())
                        }
                        
                        //enrollBookAdapter = EnrollBookAdapter(it.books as MutableList<Book>)
                        initBookRecyclerView(it.books as MutableList<Book>)
                        //setRecyclerView(it.books)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<BestSellerDto>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e(M_TAG, t.toString())
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Error

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.clone.practice/com.clone.practice.EnrollBookActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property enrollBookAdapter has not been initialized"
```

I thought when `response.body()?.let {}` run, `enrollBookAdapter` (or `booklist = it.books as mutableList<book>`) would be initialized but, it did not... What am I doing wrong? How can I initialize bookList with Books...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `initBookRecyclerView` before `enrollBookAdapter.setOnBookClickListener(object:EnrollBookAdapter.OnBookClickListener` line in `onCreate`.

After that uncomment `enrollBookAdapter = EnrollBookAdapter(it.books as MutableList<Book>)` and comment the next line.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this code from your `onCreate` method only as you are trying to use `enrollBookAdapter` variable before initialisation which is causing crash .
And you have already set this method in `initBookRecyclerView` method so no need in `onCreate` method

```
enrollBookAdapter.setOnBookClickListener(object:EnrollBookAdapter.OnBookClickListener{
            override fun onBookClick(position: Int, book: Book) {
                val intent = Intent(this@EnrollBookActivity,TalerMain::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("title",enrollBookAdapter.bookList[position].title)
                intent.putExtra("url",enrollBookAdapter.bookList[position].title)
                
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        })
```